# How can I create a Screen Saver in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

What is the extension of screens saver

and How to Set Screen saver from C#??

I have googled it and find [this](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/screensaver/screensaver.html) question

but i couldnt understood it very will!! anybody can help me?

Comment: `Screen Saver` not ServerScreen

Comment: Please read [faq] and [ask], please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most useful link:
http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/screensaver/screensaver.html

This is very easy, it is an exe file that accept special arguments, to be used by windows, to be configured and previewed and displayed as full screen

as in the article:

> **Command Line Arguments**
>
> As noted in the Introduction, a screen saver receives command-line
>   arguments which informs it which "mode" it should run in. There are
>   three arguments it might be passed in upper or lower case:
>
> /p - Show the screensaver in the screensaver selection dialog box
>
> /c - Show the screensaver configuration dialog box
>
> /s - Show the screensaver full-screen

Comment: Btw, link is down. But, based on what you're saying, then i could actually create a java program that draws a gui and takes /p or /c or /s args as parameters; and if i make an exe run the java executable then i'd have made a java-based screensaver ? ..
I'm confused by this answer